# Cant get id from route parameters

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have this type of  `<a>`

```
<a class="card_img"  [href]="'/Detail/' + food.id">
```

Route looks like:

```
  {
    path: "Detail/:{Id}",
    component: DetailInfoComponent
  }
```

**So, problem**: I can`t get **Id**, i used this method

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     this.foodID = params['Id'];
   });
```

And **foodID** is undefined. **Wrere is my fault and how i can get ID correctly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the id from the route using a snapshot or an observable. I prefer observables, because the URL can sometimes change programmatically and it's nice if the template/view updates as well.

Your routing file must look like this (without the curly braces):

```
 {
    path: "Detail/:Id",
    component: DetailInfoComponent
 }
```

Since you want to wait for data bindings to be ready, you can access it in the ngOnInit lifecycle hook.

```
  // On top of your Class - For unsubscribing from observables automatically - Injection context
  private destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.pipe(
      takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)
    ).subscribe(params => {
     console.log(params);
     this.foodID = params['Id'];
   });

  }
```

Also added a console.log to make sure you're getting the value, and nothing else is going on with async operations.

To get it using a snapshot, you can do (make sure you replace the 0 with whatever the index you expect the id to be:

```
const foodID = this.route.snapshot.url[0]!.path;
```

Keep in mind that file names and folders aren't case-sensitive on every platform. Personally i only use lowercase in Apps, but that might be a personal preference.

Also, instead of using [href], use [routerLink] to use Angular's router properly. For example.

```
<a class="card_img" [routerLink]="['/Detail/', food.id]">
```

This wil push and pop the navigation stack as expected. Make sure to include the RouterModule though in your imports. [routerLink] exxpects either a string, or an array of path elements.

Answer (score 3):

```
{
    path: "Detail/:Id",
    component: DetailInfoComponent
}
```

Route path must be without "{}"